# Нужна помощь Си

Tags: c

Суть проги в том что она выводит в последние буквы каждых слов строки.
Я написал прогу без доп. функции и все работает, но мне нужно с функцией.
Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void last_char(char str);

void last_char(char str){
    int i;
    int flag = 0;
    for( i = 0; str[i]; ++i ) {
        if( isspace(str[i]) ) {
            if( flag )
                printf("%c", str[i - 1]);
            flag = 0;
        }
        else
            flag = 1;
    }

    if( flag )
        printf("%c", str[i - 1]);
}

int main(void){
    char *str[256];
    printf("> ");
    scanf("%255[^\n]", str);
    last_char(str);
}
```

Выводит следующие. ошибки:

> 10:error: subscripted value is neither array or pointer.
>   11:error: subscripted value is neither array or pointer.
>   13:error: subscripted value is neither array or pointer.
>   21:error: subscripted value is neither array or pointer.

Я новичок в программировании, прошу, помогите!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
void last_char(char *str){
    ...

int main(void){
    char str[256];
```

Comment: Как раз хотел написать что разобрался!
Но все же спасибо за столь быстрый ответ !!!

Comment: @Brentimusss На здоровье. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: @Brentimusss если ответ помог вам, [отметьте его решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Прошу прощения что не нажал сразу!